Is there a .cls file of the layout of the Latex Companion 3rd edition?
The layout of the Latex Companion 3rd edition is really elegant.

I understand (Production Notes, end of the document) that an assembly of 140 packages was used.
Sorry for my naive question, but are you aware of a .cls file for this format? Or perhaps a simplified version? a Git we can get inspiration from ?
Maybe a copyright issue from the publisher if not available  (?)

Not quite what you're looking for but the examples and their class files can be found at the tlc3-examples repository. Also on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tlc3-examples
